# Comment traduire (le degré ou seuil) du « material (impact) » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, adjectifs

Dans un processus de fabrication on a une obligation d'avertir si un changement de procédé cause ou a un « [material](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/material) impact » au/sur (le) produit fini...

Quel adjectif peut-on employer pour qualifier cet « impact » (seuil) et pourquoi ? On peut entre autres s'appuyer sur la compréhension du terme, sur une équivalence usuelle de cooccurrences, une prépondérance d'exemples, des comparaisons de traductions bilingues etc.

Comment: Le dentifrice (https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=64535020#64535020)  n'est pas un matériel, mais un produit. « Le changement de couleur impacte le produit. »

Comment: @Personne Il s'agit systématiquement de l'adjectif (_material impact_, c'est l'impact qui est « material » et non _impact on the material_), que ce soit dans le fil de discussion ou ici. La question du fil est de quel degré d'impact s'agit-il et la question ici est comment le traduire soit en connaissant le degré évoqué dans la langue source soit par une comparaison de la cooccurrence usuelle dans ce genre de contexte en français etc. Dans le fil j'utilise des exemples concrets, comme la couleur du produit, pour voir ce qui usuellement atteint ou non ce degré-là.

Comment: Le changement de ce composant n'impacte pas la qualité du produit.

Answer (score 4):

In such context, material probably means "having real importance", then a translaton could be :

> une incidence importante (ou significative) sur le produit fini.

Comment: Cette [discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=64535020#64535020) change-t-elle quelque chose à ton analyse ?

Comment: Je conçois qu'on puisse employer "material" pour indiquer un impact sur quelque chose de physique (comme par analogie avec *material assets* que l'on oppose à *immaterial assets*). Je pense que ce cas de figure est (très) minoritaire. Dans des traductions comportant immaterial impact, cela donne "impact/incidence négligeable/non significatif/peu important/minime"