# Peut-on traduire « material impact » par « impact matériel » ?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, adjectifs, faux-amis

Un changement dans un procédé de fabrication pourrait entraîner un « [material](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/material) impact » sur le produit fini. On peut identifier certaines [traductions](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/53750/26366).

Pourquoi peut-on ou non traduire ceci par « impact (ou un autre substantif, peu importe) [*matériel*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mat%C3%A9riel) », s'agit-il d'un faux-ami, la traduction s'appuierait-elle sur un sens assez usuel de l'adjectif matériel pour être équivalente au sens en anglais ?

Comment: _Matériel_ par opposition à _immatériel_, ou _abstrait_. C'est à dire un impact non pas subjectif, mais _concret_. Je rapprocherais _matériel_ de _concret_ ici. La _matière_ s'oppose à ce qui n'est que dans l'esprit, en quelque sorte.

Comment: En anglais, *material* a des sens que *matériel* n'a pas en français; *material impact* peut signifie *impact important* ou *impact substantiel*, et je ne crois pas que *impacte matériel* puisse signifie ça. C'est un ami à moitié faux. [See dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/material): "important or having an important effect" (en français, "important ou ayant un effet important").

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec Peter. Il ne faut garder que le sens de _substantiel_ en français.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comment traduire (le degré ou seuil) du « material (impact) » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53750/comment-traduire-le-degr%c3%a9-ou-seuil-du-material-impact)

Answer (score 3):

Dans l'expression anglaise "material impact", le sens du mot "material" n'est pas "matériel" par opposition à abstrait ou immatériel. Le sens est celui de "significatif" par opposition à insignifiant ou négligeable. Traduire cette expression par "impact matériel" est un contre-sens.

On peut traduire par "impact [ou conséquence] non-négligeable", "impact significatif [ou conséquence significative]".

Comment: I disagree about "significant". I take "material" here to mean "of the sort and degree that makes a measurable difference". (There is overlap with "degree", but I say that "sort" is an essential ingredient too.)

Answer (score 2):

En partant de l'idée que ce qui est *matériel*, *concret*, *perceptible*, *substantiel*, *qui peut être saisi par les sens* s'oppose à ce qui est *immatériel*, *abstrait*, *imperceptible*, *qu'on ne peut saisir par les sens*, je traduirais *material impact* par *impact concret*, *impact réel*, *impact substantiel* ou encore *impact perceptible*. Peut-être même *impact effectif*.

Le contraire serait un *impact immatériel*, ou *imperceptible concrètement* autrement dit pas vraiment un impact. Par exemple, dans certains contextes, je suppose qu'un *material impact* pourrait causer une perte financière réelle, par opposition à un *impact imperceptible ou insignifiant* qui ne causerait aucune perte réelle.